# How to make scaling to persist with CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, ipad

I am creating some animation on my application and the code below zooms out an object till it disappears. I can't figure out how to make the object to disappear and keep that way, ie. how to make the animation stay put after it finishes. Any gotchas on that? Cheers!

```
        CABasicAnimation* zoomOut = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
        zoomOut.duration = 1;
        zoomOut.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
        [draggedObject addAnimation:zoomOut forKey:nil];
```

Comment: Can you add some more details about what happens to the object after the animation is finished?

Comment: Yes sorry. The object animates (1 sec), it zooms out to the infinity (it disappears) but then after 1 sec the object's size is restored to its original size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so this happens because the animation doesn't actually change the underlying property, which is why it jumps back after the animation is complete.

Try adding this line before the line starting the animation -
zoomOut.removedOnCompletion = NO;

Comment: Thanks Nick. It needs the zoomOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards; also

Comment: It does yeah, sorry missed that line.  So is your code working now?

Answer (score 5):

I found it. It also needs the two methods below:

```
        zoomOut.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        zoomOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
```